# Content Porter - Don't update dependencies if they already exist in destination CM

Tags: content-porter-2013, web8.5, content-porter

In previous versions of the Content Porter client, there used to be a separate option on whether or not to update dependent content that already exists in the destination CM (if you include dependent content in the import).

[image]

The latest version has the “*Which dependent content would you like to include in the import?*” screen, but this seems to be whether or not to include those items in the import package, rather than whether to update them if they already exist.

[image]

I want to do an import and create new dependent items (mainly components) if they don’t already exist. However, I definitely don’t want to update anything that already exists in the destination CM.

Is this possible (without cherry-picking through hundreds of components to select them individually if they don’t already exist)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the answer to this in the [Configuring this import](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Content%20Porter-v2/GUID-BFB191CD-94BF-4F49-8C6E-31999907829D) page of the Content Porter online documentation:

> 6. If you are importing into SDL Tridion 2013 Content Manager or older, under Do you want to update dependencies, select one of the
>      following:
>
>    - Select Yes if you want Content Porter to always perform an update of a dependency if the item being imported depends on an item that is
>        already present on the destination Content Manager.
>    - Select No if you want Content Porter to never perform an update of a dependency if the item being imported depends on an item that is
>        already present on the destination Content Manager.
>
> **Note: When importing into SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 Content Manager or later, this option is not available, because dependencies cannot be
>   updated, only created.**

So it appears that I don't need to worry about it, as none of the existing content will be updated (unless it is explicitly checked in the item selection screen).

Comment: Makes sense, huh? It is so nice if you can make people happy by removing features. :-)

Comment: Yes, that's true. Maybe a little note in the GUI would give further reassurance to users too.